# Control width render animation in Codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have a page which has multiple vertical sections, each with a thermometer type control i have built, rendered on each. How do i code it so that when the page loads that the 'mercury' width, of all the sections, can grow in an animated way to fill the thermometers?

I have tried the samples provided for making the form.animateLayout(3000); but i've been unsuccessful in getting individual controls to grow their width concurrently..

FYI the thermometer is a Container, with a Table as its Layout, with a red Label placed on the container, at a specific width

```
outlineContainer.add(table.createConstraint().widthPercentage(90), mercuryLabel);
```

This is how i guarantee the thermometer mercury is at the correct width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to animate the direct parent of the growing element so something like this should work:

```
mercuryLabel.setWidth(0);
outlineContainer.animateLayout(1000);
```

Make sure you don't have `revalidate`, `repaint` or other related code that will disrupt this.